# iPhone Provisioning Profile problems

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm having trouble getting the Application Identifier or Bundle Identifier set up.  In my distribution profile, I have included the identifier "com.***.***, and then copied it exactly into the the app's Info.plist file under "Bundle Identifier".  In the past, this has done the trick, but now I'm getting the error

Provisioning profile 'irow beta' specificies the identifier 'com.***.***' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.yourcompany.***.

So it seems that its somehow still using the default of com.yourcompany.APPLICATION_NAME, but it shouldn't after I have changed it in the Info.plist, right?

I think this means that xcode isn't recognizing that PLIST for some reason, because when I change the name of the icon file, for example, or other such attributes, nothing changes.  If this is the problem, how do I make xcode recognize the PLIST?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure, that if you'll go in xcode to your target->properties and change it there, it will catch, so the icon. Probably the plist you're trying to change doesn't appear in build settings of a certain target, that's why you don't see the change.